# Upcasting and Downcasting skipping heirarchy in C++?

Tags: c++, casting

I've searched for this particular question but couldn't find it so here it is. Is it fine to upcast or downcast by skipping the classes in the middle?

Example code-

```
class Base { }
class Derived : public Base { }
class DerivedOfDerived : public Derived { }
class DerivedOfDOD : public DerivedOfDerived { }

int main()
{
    DerivedOfDOD *dodod = new DerivedOfDOD();
    Base *b = static_cast<Base *>(dodod);
    Derived *d = static_cast<Derived *>(b);
    back_to_b = static_cast<Base *>(d);
    DerivedOfDerived *dod = static_cast<DerivedOfDerived *>(back_to_b);
    delete dodod;
}
```

Is this valid code? And of an explanation for how the compiler manages the addresses and this sort of casting would be very appreciated.

Comment: `b` is not a `DerivedOfDOD`/`Derived`, so any usage of `dodod`, `d` would be UB.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks for that, I've updated the code with what I really meant.

Comment: Now, your code is valid.

Comment: Of course it's valid.

Comment: But you have memory leak. and as your classes are not virtual, you have to delete it  from `dodod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it fine to upcast or downcast by skipping the classes in the middle?

Yes.

> Is this valid code?

Yes. (If we ignore the memory leak)

P.S. Upcasting is implicit, so `Base *b = dodod;` is sufficient.

Comment: A memory leak just makes the code fishy, but it does not make it invalid.

Comment: @j6t depends on what you mean by "valid" and on the context of the memory leak.

Comment: By "valid" I mean that the Standard does not mandate that memory must be released or objects be destroyed (or else the program exhibits undefined behavior).